# Path double cover, recursion set up

Tags: algorithm, graph

I'm working on path double cover problem. I have undirected connected graph G and and I change every edge to 2 directed edges and each of them is in opposite direction. Then the goal is to find set of paths(no loops) in this directed graph so that every vertex is used once as start of path and once as end of another path. Each of directed edges are used exactly once.

[undirected graph G](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYVBD.png)
[directed graph G](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBruF.png)

For this example there is set of paths P={(1,2,4),(4,3,1),(2,1,3),(3,4,2)}.

There are currently known 2 graphs K3 and K5 (fully connected graphs with 3 and 5 vertices) which cannot be covered in this way.

I want to make script which will find me this covering or tell me if there isn't one. I tried to generate all possible paths and then search in them but for bigger graph this approach isn't usable (n! complexity). I don't know how to set up the recursion so I can keep track of what I've used. I don't care about time complexity but it would be awesome if you had any tip for doing it more quickly. :D

Thanks for any suggestions. :D

Answer (score 0):

Your definition is a bit confusing-  you say that you need to find a set of paths (no loops) in the directed graph, with 1 outgoing edge per vertex. There is no way for these edges not to form a loop (at most `n - 1` edges can be tree edges).

I'm going to assume that you instead mean "only one cycle; no subcycles".

In that case, your task becomes that of determining whether your graph has a [Hamiltonian Cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) or not.

We can use [Ore's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ore%27s_theorem) as a quick check:

> If deg v + deg w ≥ n for every pair of distinct non-adjacent vertices v and w of G then G is Hamiltonian.

Note that this says "if" and not "iif" / "if and only if", so a graph be Hamiltonian, and not satisfy this check.

To take things one step further, we can use the [Bondy–Chvátal theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path#/Bondy%E2%80%93Chv%C3%A1tal_theorem):

> A graph is Hamiltonian if and only if its closure is Hamiltonian.

And we obtain its closure in a similar method to what we did for Ore's Theorem check- we repeatedly add a new edge connecting a nonadjacent pair of vertices `u` and `v` with `deg(v) + deg(u) ≥ n` until no more pairs with this property can be found.

Once this is done, we check whether the closure is Hamiltonian. If the closure is a [complete graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph), then it is Hamiltonian. I was unable to find any proof that the closure will be complete iif the graph g is Hamiltonian, however it does seem to happen with every example graph I can conjure up, so at least it may be a stronger correlation than Ore's Theorem.

In the end, you just need to determine if the graph has Hamiltonian Cycle. I've listed above two ways you can perform quadratic-time checks to positively identify some of such graph (maybe all, again- not sure of the completeness of the closure bit).

Comment: this graph was just for illustration it can be any complete graph like K6 or any bipartite (those are proven to have double cover)

Comment: I didn't mean the illustration (I admittedly didn't look at that until just now), I was referring to: "Then the goal is to find set of paths(no loops) in this directed graph", because there must be loops in your solution

Comment: there dont have to be loops bcs if you have path graph with 3 vertices(like straight line) then it has this set P={(1,2,3),(3,2),(2,1)} its is proven that this double cover can be found on any tree

Comment: @PatrikKula I think we are both misunderstanding each other. I misunderstood part the problem- we only consider the start/stop of each path (we can reuse intermediate vertices). On the other hand-  the counterexample you just provided creates a cycle (1->3->2->1...). I stand by the statement that your solution will make loops

Comment: Yea I think we are... we can reuse vertices but only in different paths, every vertex must be starting and ending vertex once and every directed edge must be used exactly once in whole set of paths. So If I understand it correctly then I should make hamiltonian cycle with directed graph and then divide it to paths, right? I don't think that we can do it with C4

Comment: I think the Hamiltonian cycle stuff may be a red herring. I'm thinking the problem as I understand it now might be special case of finding an edge cover- possibly we can transform an edge cover to compose edges to form paths, so each vertex is a start/stop once.
However, I'm still not quite understanding something. Why is K3 not solvable? Seems [(1,2), (2,3), (3,1)] would work. Each vertex is the start of exactly one path, end of one, and no edge directed edge is revisited ever.

Comment: its because you have to use every directed edge once (in both ways)... so even edges (3,1),(2,1) and (1,3) must be present in solution... from edge {1,2} you make two directed edges (1,2) and (2,1)